# How to handle conditional rendering of views related to same controller's action?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I am developing a simple CRMish application. Let's say I can create tasks and clients. Both can be created independently, but they can also be created in a process. I have a views called `create.blade.php` for these two actions.

When you are creating a task for example, at some point you have a button choose a customer / create a customer which opens a modal dialog (so you can pick a customer and assign it to a task in one step :)). And here it starts to get muddy. I want my form part from `create.blade.php` to be rendered in modal dialog and to do so I need to fetch this hitting my **create action**, which normally returns full form that extends `master.blade.php`.

How would you handle this kind of design problem? For now it would be a little, innocent switch or if before `return view()` in my **create action** but I know that it will look like spaghetti carbonara at some point.

My ideas are as follows:

- ifs/switch as long as it's readable and it's only about returning
  different views (but you know it will include logic, different
  variables etc. at some point..)
- move ifs/switch logic to some request class and call `return
  view($request->getView())` so my controller will be a little bit
  cleaner and follow SRP
- create different classes for "ajax" requests, and "normal" requests.
- same as above but because the logic of fetching some data used in
  form etc. are common for both of the scenarios I can create a base
  abstract class of TaskController and than extend this for "normal"
  request and "ajax" request scenario. This is most advanced idea, but
  I think i follow SRP as well as I remove code duplication cause
  fetching common data will be placed in abstract class

Do you have any other ideas of how to handle this?

Comment: Make a **modal-dialog.blade.php**. You can use it in create.blade.php via @include('modal-dialog') or return it for an ajax request.

Comment: Yeah, but create.blade.php already extends master view. So it renders full html page. Should i move those conditionals to the view?

Comment: Don´t overengineer. Why not making an extra create.blade.php which isn´t extending master? Later on you can see which parts you can split in partials for reuse over multiple views.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the tip. After reading all this "design" books I even try to apply these patterns to everyday tasks. KISS

Comment: Your welcome. These design patterns are very good to know of (specially when working in a team) but after all what counts is that you know your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with a little conditional in my `create.blade.php` view.

```
@extends((( Request::ajax()) ? 'layouts.modal' : 'layouts.master' ))
```

According to @Kristo I wont overengineer, and stick with this simple & readable solution.

**UPDATE**

I have created a little extension, as I decided that I will not load my modals via Ajax but simply inject them on compile time. Here is the code :)

https://github.com/3amprogrammer/modal-blade-extension